# Type inference when creating a partially applied function

Tags: scala, type-inference

When I do:

```
def x(i: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int) = i

x(_: Int, _: Int, 3)
```

Why do I have to specify that the first two arguments are "Int"?

Is there a way to make the compiler infer types, so that I can type:

```
  x(_, _, 3)
```

Comment: It's very likely related to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3293 Although compiler has enough info, the flow of inference is restricted to make implementation simplier.

Comment: @om-nom-nom except that there's no polymorphism here...

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You always have to be explicit about the parameter types of anonymous functions, unless a function type is expected. "Partial application" is just a syntactical sugar for creating an anonymous function.

**Long answer:**

First, note that you don't *always* have to supply type arguments when partially applying `x`. Consider this example:

```
def x(i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) = i

def g(f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(1, 2)

// types are inferred!
g(x(_, _, 3)) // evaluates to 1

// again, types are inferred
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = x(_, _, 3)
```

So clearly it helps to be in a context where a `(Int, Int) => Int` is expected.

Second, note that you're defining an anonymous function. You could write it more explicitly like this:

```
(a, b) => x(a, b, 3)
```

Written this way, it should be more clear that the defining context (i.e., as a lone expression) sets up no expectation for the type of the anonymous function. In the application of `g`, on the other hand, `g`'s parameter type implies an expectation for a specific function type.

The compiler could, in principle, infer the types of `a` and `b` from the type of `x`, but it does not, as specified in §6.23 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (bold-emphasis added):

> The anonymous function (*x<sub>1</sub>*: *T<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>n</sub>*: *T<sub>n</sub>*) => *e* maps parameters *x<sub>i</sub>* of types *T<sub>i</sub>* to a result given by expression *e*. [...]
>
> If the expected type of the anonymous function is of the form scala.FunctionN[*S<sub>1</sub>*,...,*S<sub>n</sub>*, *R*], the expected type of *e* is *R* and the type *T<sub>i</sub>* of any of the parameters *x<sub>i</sub>* can be omitted, in which case *T<sub>i</sub>* = *S<sub>i</sub>* is assumed. **If the expected type of the anonymous function is some other type, all formal parameter types must be explicitly given**, and the expected type of *e* is undefined.